# Adding a css class to select in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, select, simple-form, slim-lang

I've been trying to make the following class applies on the select/dropdown, but I couldn't!

```
 = f.select attr, [1,2,3],  class: 'form-control', include_blank: true
```

I tried to read the rails code, [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/select.rb) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb).
it's like it is not implemented ?
but it works for text fields:

```
 = f.search_field attr, options.merge(class: 'form-control')
```

I'm using [slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails) and [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select` takes 2 hash options, first for 'select options' and another for 'html'.

Try following:

```
= f.select(attr, [1,2,3], { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control' })
```

Comment: Thanks! it works !!, I tried it in all possible ways, but didn't think about putting the class inside {} !

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can add class and Inline CSS to select tag

```
<%= select_tag :db_field, options_for_select(@users.select([:email, 'users.id']).map{|user| [user.email, user.id]}), class: 'class_name_1 class_name_2', style: "min-width: 100px;" %>
```