# Unable to add css class in simple-form select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, slim-lang

I'm trying to add a CSS for the select field in simple form but it is not applying. I tried in the following ways,

```
= f.select :user_types, options_for_select([['Type', ''], ['College', 'admin'], ['Student', 'student']], {required: true, selected: ''}), input_html: {id: 'college_admin_type', class: 'form-control custom-drop-icon'}

= f.select :user_types, options_for_select([['Type', ''], ['College', 'admin'], ['Student', 'student']], {required: true, selected: ''}), wrapper_html: {id: 'college_admin_type', class: 'form-control custom-drop-icon'}

= f.select :user_types, options_for_select([['Type', ''], ['College', 'admin'], ['Student', 'student']], {required: true, selected: ''}), id: 'college_admin_type', class: 'form-control custom-drop-icon'
```

I found a similar kind of answer but unable to figure it. Here's a link [Adding a css class to select in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37190047/11000380).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `simple_form` you should use its `as: :select` notation

```
= f.input :user_types, as: :select,
  collection: [['Type', ''], ['College', 'admin'], ['Student', 'student']],
  input_html: { id: 'college_admin_type', class: 'form-control custom-drop-icon' }
```

But if you are using default rails `select` helper, you should pass html options as second options hash.

```
= f.select(:user_types, [['Type', ''], ['College', 'admin'], ['Student', 'student']], {}, { class: 'form-control custom-drop-icon' })
```

See also [Ruby on Rails form_for select field with class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081944/1154044)